# Reading in data file and names file as a single pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'd like to import a dataset from the UCL depository as a pandas data frame.

The problem is that the bulk of data sits in one file (wdbc.data) and the column names in another (wdbc.names), and I don't know how to read them in together as a single pandas data frame.

Thanks for any help!

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data')
df2 = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.names')
df_final = df1.append(df2)

ERROR MESSAGE: 
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 3
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) instead of `append`?

Comment: The problem occurs at `read_csv`, check the seperator of your files, the default is set to comma.

Comment: Second is metadata file

Answer (score 1):

The "wdbc.names" file doesn't have useful data for column names. So, I found column names from Kaggle referring to the same dataset.
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data.
Then you can try like below.

```
import pandas as pd
names = ['id','diagnosis','radius_mean','texture_mean','perimeter_mean','area_mean','smoothness_mean','compactness_mean','concavity_mean','concave points_mean','symmetry_mean','fractal_dimension_mean','radius_se','texture_se','perimeter_se','area_se','smoothness_se','compactness_se','concavity_se','concave points_se','symmetry_se','fractal_dimension_se','radius_worst','texture_worst','perimeter_worst','area_worst','smoothness_worst','compactness_worst','concavity_worst','concave points_worst','symmetry_worst','fractal_dimension_worst']
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data')
df.columns = names
df.head()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJNFD.png)

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I reckon could use a bit of context (i.e. where you got the names from).  Seems to me you could get them from the `.names` file, but it's horribly formatted, with a nested list within bullet point `7` of that file.  Perhaps comment the code snippet to that effect, or point out that it's pretty hard to get the names out of that file via machine reading of the file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).